# Javascript - Convert string into a multi-dimensional array and then display the output

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I convert a string into a multi-dimensional array and then display the output?

Below is my attempt.

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
var str = "(id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id), lastname),location)"; 
var match = str.split(',');
var ele1=match[0];
var ele2=match[1];
var ele3=match[2];
var ele4=match[3];
var ele5=match[4];
var ele6=match[5];
var ele7=match[6];

var n=ele1+'<br>'+ele2+'<br>'+ele3+'<br>'+ele4+'<br>'+ele5+'<br>'+ele6+'<br>'+ele7;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =n;}
```

Comment: maybe you could add the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this. Is this what you are trying to get?
and Thanks to LPL I edited DRY code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "(id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id), lastname),location)"; 
  
  var match = str.replace(/[{()}]/g, '').split(',');

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = match.join("<br />");;
}
myFunction()
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `join` instead of repeating code like that.

```js
var print = function() {
  var str = "id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id), lastname),location"; 
  var dataArray = str.split(',');
  document.getElementById("my-demo").innerHTML = dataArray.join("<br />");
}
print();
```

```html
<div id="my-demo"></div>
```